# Orient text vertically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation

I would like to set every character of label to vertical as shown below:

```
G
R
A
P
H

L
A
B
L
E
```

Any help is appreciated, you can find the code below:

```
var centerG = g.append('g')
    .attr('x', ((width / 2) - (barWidth / 2)))
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

centerG.append('text')
    .text('GRAPH LABEL')
    .attr("font-family", "Arimo")
    .attr("font-size", "18px")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
    .attr("letter-spacing", "1.5px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width / 2) + barOffset) +
        ", " + yHeight + ") rotate(270)")
    .attr("class", "centerLabelText")
    .attr("y", 0)
```

Comment: .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" ) //did u try transform by degrees? More http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html

Comment: @Luckyy this not working. I had tried!

Comment: If you can share fiddler or any online link, can help. Because it is expected to work. You just need to take care of correct node you are rotating.

Comment: here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prashantparekh/38wuz5f8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title (*"Rotate every character of text to vertical"*, which I edited) is misleading: you don't want to *rotate* every character of the text. If you stop to see, each character in the text is in the correct position! There is nothing rotated here.

What you want is to *orient the text vertically*.

You can use a function that you pass the selection, using `call`, and that split the text into its characters, repositioning them. Here is an example that I just created:

```
function vertical(elem) {
  var xPos = elem.attr("x")
  var letters = elem.text().split("");
  var tspan = elem.text(null);
  while (letters.length) {
    tspan.append("tspan")
      .text(letters.shift())
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("x", xPos)
  }
}
```

And here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var text = svg.append('text')
  .text('GRAPH LABEL')
  .attr("font-family", "Arimo")
  .attr("font-size", "18px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("fill", "#444")
  .attr("letter-spacing", "1.5px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", 150)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .call(vertical);

function vertical(elem) {
  var xPos = elem.attr("x")
  var letters = elem.text().split("");
  var tspan = elem.text(null);
  while (letters.length) {
    tspan.append("tspan")
      .text(letters.shift())
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("x", xPos)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg height="300"></svg>
```